# Form submit from JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form on a page I want to submit using JavaScript:

```html
<script>
  function deleteFromlist(listname, listvalue)
  {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
       document.getElementById('fromList').value=listname;
       document.getElementById('deleteRecord').value=listvalue;
       document.getElementById('watchlistForm').submit(); // Fails here
    }
  }
</script>

<form method='POST'
      id='watchlistForm'
      enctype='multipart/form-data'
      action='process.php'>

  <input type='text' name='fromList' id='fromList' value=''>
  <input type='text' name='deleteRecord' id='deleteRecord' value=''>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

The JavaScript function is called from a `href` in an table elsewhere on the page. It correctly populates the input fields, but it fails with this message:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function 
> document.getElementById('watchlistForm').submit();

If I replace the doc....submit(); with

```
alert(document.getElementById('watchlistForm').innerHTML
```

then I get the expected output in the alert box. Hence

```
document.getElementById('watchlistForm')
```

does resolve to the form element.

Adding a submit button on the form works as expected.

Why is this not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't you mean "document.getElementById('deleteRecord').value=listvalue;" ? I think you forgot the .value

Comment: Do you have multiple watchlistForm(s)?

Comment: Try checking the output of  `console.log(document.getElementById('watchlistForm').submit)` - if that's not a function, it will give you a clue.

Comment: I tried your snippet with the ".value" fixed and I see a post request firing in the console. The request fails because I don't have the endpoint php but at least it fires.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ae3o4xj/ it works here if you add .value as commented above

Comment: @Jonas: cut and paste error. Thanks.

Comment: That's weird, the fiddle linked above works with the name="submit" thing.

Comment: @JonasGrumann [Are you sure?](https://jsfiddle.net/d3a6fz97/)

Comment: Yes, in the console I have: VM166:60 POST https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/process.php 404 (NOT FOUND) and no TypeError

Comment: @JonasGrumann The original fiddle that baao posted doesn't have a "name" input. The one I linked to does and, at least for me, has the `submit not a function` error.

Comment: You are right, I wrongly assumed baao had copy/pasted the code, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erk, it seems that the button *named* 'submit' was masking out the method. Changing:

```
 input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'
```

to

```
 input type='submit' name='submitButton' value='submit'
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense. I forgot you could access form elements by name through the form itself.